# Installing 64-bit open jdk on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, java

How can I install open jdk 64-bit on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I have installed by running this command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. Is there any way to specify 64-bit while installing?

Comment: And what does java --version show?

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre ?